# What percentage of screen power usage is healthy?

Tags: battery-life

Using GSam, the screen uses about 50% of power compared to apps. Is this normal/healthy?

Comment: Yup. It happens. On my S5 I get at least 40% on the screen.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this is completely normal especially on high-resolution devices.  It takes a lot of juice to produce all that light, switch colors, etc.  Activities like watching videos will exacerbate this.

The only times you will usually see the screen not use the most battery is if you have the screen off for a long time, or if you play a really intensive game.

Comment: A really intensive game doesn't make the screen drain battery juice?

Comment: Not if you keep the screen off when playing it, no #D

Comment: @Rexford I said nothing of the kind, I said it will be exceeded by the use of the app.